# Hibernate:one-to-one related entity inserted into DB instead of to be updated

Tags: hibernate, entity, cascade, one-to-one

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {
private Person person;
...
```

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entry.User" table="users">
        <id name="usaa">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username"/>
        <property name="password" column="password"/>
        <property name="enabled" column="enabled"/>

        <many-to-one name="person" class="entry.Person" column="perid" not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true"/>            
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**person.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entry.Person" table="person">
        <id name="id" column="perid">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="firstname"/>
        <property name="lastName" column="lastname"/>
        <property name="middleName" column="middlename"/>
        <property name="dob" column="dob"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thus, `one-to-one` relation designed above.

**Correctly working DAO method:**

```
public void createUser(User user) {
user.setPerson(new Person());
getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
..
```

when `User` is inserted into DB,that `Person` is inserted into DB automatically also.It's OK.

**Unexpectedly working DAO method:**

```
public void editUser(User user, Person person) {
user.setPerson(person);
getHibernateTemplate().update(user);
...
```

Problem occurred, when `User` is updated with new `Person` data.

New Person id generated and **one new row inserted** into Person table.

How to do that,`Person` appropriate row **to be updated** and not inserted?

Thank you for help.

**Assumption:**

I assume,that problem is in autoincrementing `id`s when refer to the entity.
It looks like, autoincrementing should be avoided in case of `update` or `saveOrUpdate` method calls.
Autoincrementing should be called,when entity firstly created and inserted into DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct,

> It looks like, autoincrementing should be avoided in case of update or saveOrUpdate method calls. Autoincrementing should be called,when entity firstly created and inserted into DB.

You do not have to wroory about all these, hibernate will use a simple rule to do this, **when the id of the object is null it fires an insert query if it is any other value it fires an update query with that value**.

In your case before you save user, set the `person` id to oldPersonId.

```
public void editUser(User user, Person person) {
person.SetId(oldPersonId);
user.setPerson(person);
getHibernateTemplate().update(user);
```

This will fire the update query instead of insert.

Comment: thank you for reply.I can't understand where to get `oldPersonId`

Comment: ManuPK,thanks a lot, I understand your point,just read,that you typed in bold)))